# InvalidFieldValue in MarketingCloud for Transactional Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

Currently there are few emails which are not delivered with status set as 'not-sent'.

The emails are sent via Transactional Messaging API.

In SFMC Transactional Journey View, it just says `InvalidFieldValue`

Is there a way to check which fields are causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get access to the payload that was sent to the API and compare it against the field definitions? That would be the quickest way to determine what field(s) are causing the issues.