# Marketing Cloud Splunk Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, error-messages, email-tracking, log-analysis

Is there any guide to integrate Splunk with Marketing Cloud?

There are no solutions (or addons) available online, or any documentation that Salesforce Support could share.

As I understand, Splunk provides better insights (specifically error analysis) compared to Marketing Cloud tools as suggested by Salesforce Support.

Comment: What specifically from SFMC would you want to track in Splunk?

Comment: error reason details for not-sent emails...which just says field type mismatch

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373266/invalidfieldvalue-in-marketingcloud-for-transactional-emails

Comment: would be interesting to know which field had mismatch, without manual comparison...and saving the email payload for each call...

Comment: There are no SFMC integration points that'll output that level of info.  You'll need to align your API payloads with the target schema in SFMC.

Comment: agreed...after few manual checks, found out this was due to field length issue for one of the text fields